# How to find inverse of function $f(x, y)$?

Tags: functions, relations

I am aware of the [method to find inverse function](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ec5YYVxyq44) $f^{-1}(x)$ of $f(x)$, which is

- Replace $f(x)$ with $y$
- Switch $x$'s and $y$'s
- Solve for $y$
- Replace $y$ with $f^{-1}(x)$

the above method worked well until I found following problem,

> Let $f\colon \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ denotes a bijective function defined as; 
> $f(x, y) = (x + y + 1, x - y - 1)$,
> then, find the inverse $f^{-1}(x, y)$

can anybody please tell me how to solve such kind of problems?

Comment: You claim the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$, but that doesn't seem to be so. The same happens with the codomain. And are you sure you want $\{(x+y+1),(x−y−1)\}$? I think you mean $((x+y+1),(x−y−1))$.

Comment: yes.. edited. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Replace $f\left(x,y\right)$ by $\left(u,v\right)$ resulting in:
  $x+y+1=u$ and $x-y-1=v$
- Switch $x$ and $u$ and switch $y$ and $v$ resulting in: $u+v+1=x$
  and $u-v-1=y$
- Solve for $u$ and $v$ resulting in: $u=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y$
  and $v=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y-1$
- Replace $\left(u,v\right)$ with $f^{-1}\left(x,y\right)$ resulting
  in: $f^{-1}\left(x,y\right)$=$\left(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y,\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y-1\right)$

So, same procedure. This gives you the inverse of function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $f\left(x,y\right)=\left(x+y+1,x-y-1\right)$.
I think (as Git Gud) that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x, y) =(x + y + 1,x - y - 1)$$
$$x\to x+y+1,y\to x-y-1$$
$$x+y+1=a,x-y-1=b\Rightarrow x=\frac{a+b}{2}, y=\frac{a-b-2}{2}$$
$$f^{-1}(x, y) = \left(\frac{x + y}{2},\frac{x-y-2}{2}\right)$$